# FindControl in GridTemplateColumn in RadGrid

Tags: c#, telerik, radgrid

Does anyone know how to FindControl in the GridTemplateColumn in a RadGrid. I can get it to find it find in EditForm. But it can't seem to find it in the GridTemplateColumn. I am trying to do this in the ItemDataBound event. The if statement never becomes true and never gets into to FindControl.

This is what I am trying:

```
if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
  {
    GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
    DropDownList ddlAccountLookup = (DropDownList)item["Account"].FindControl("ddlAccountLookup");
  }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Telerik's support website](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/316967-griddataitem.aspx) shows exactly the same way you are doing it:

```
if (e.Item is GridDataItem)  
{  
   GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;  
   Label lbl = (Label)item["IsSportingEvent"].FindControl("LabelSporting");  
}
```

I suggest that you put a break point on `item["Account"]` and do a watch to inspect what controls are contained inside it.

Answer (score 0):

If your UniqueName is not "Account" the code can't find the controls which are in "Account"