# Cannot see Telerik RadTextBox in my code-behind

Tags: c#, telerik

I have a RadTextBox and I need my back-end to know the Text of it.
However, I get an error when trying to access it from anywhere within my backend:

*txtnote does not exist in the current context.*

```
    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Notes" UniqueName="Notes">
       <ItemTemplate>
          <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtnote" InputType="Text" Width="100%" Rows="4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("notes")%>' TextMode="MultiLine"></telerik:RadTextBox>
       </ItemTemplate>
    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can get the Text value of this?

Comment: Show the code behind.

Comment: As mentioned above, I cannot access this from anywhere. My backend is completely empty, just an empty page_load method.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936544/findcontrol-in-gridtemplatecolumn-in-radgrid) out.

Comment: If you have the ability try posting on their forums, they have good support. Only things I can suggest would be restart your IDE. I find Visual Studio and Telerik controls sometimes get into a funk. Do you have multiple versions of their WPF controls installed on the system? I've had issues where different versions of the software wouldn't play nicely together.

Comment: You are in a template of a data-bound control, so you can't directly access the server element in code-behind.  There are lots of ways to get it though, you just have to search.  Such as https://www.telerik.com/forums/accessing-new-value-from-textbox-in-itemtemplate-edititemtemplate-in-radgrid

Comment: I had restarted my Visual Studio several times, which did not change the situation.
Thanks @Seano666 , this led me to a decent solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Seano666, I found a solution. This is what I ended up using:

```
RadTextBox txtbox = (RadTextBox)item["Notes"].FindControl("txtnote");
string WhatIWantedToFind = txtbox.Text;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! I guess I could have made some free internet points here, oh well :)